# ERROR in Module.createRequire is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I tried to create react app with node version 12.1.0 but it warned me that my minimum node version should be at least 14.0.  I used `nvm` to change my node version to 14.0 and created react app.
However, I want to use my app on node version 12.1.0. So I changed to node version v12.1.0  but I got:

> "ERROR in Module.createRequire is not a function" error. Also " ERROR
> in   Error: Child compilation failed: Module.createRequire is not a
> function "

Comment: Did  the answers solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunatelly not :(

Comment: `nvm use stable` worked for me. It was using an old buggy Node version.

Comment: you will also need to use older version of `create-react-app` if you want to use older version of `node`

Answer (score 40):

As we can read in official [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html):

### Create React App

> Create React App is a comfortable environment for learning React, and
> is the best way to start building a new single-page application in
> React.
>
> It sets up your development environment so that you can use the latest
> JavaScript features, provides a nice developer experience, and
> optimizes your app for production. **You’ll need to have Node >= 14.0.0
> and npm >= 5.6 on your machine.**

So these are `requirements` that you `must meet` and it seems that it cannot be avoided `that way` .

Comment: This was the issue for me. I needed to upgrade my nodejs to 14+ and was at 10. I didn't need to update npm per the instructions because I am using Yarn.

Answer (score 10):

Try completely updating the newest, stable version of both nodejs and npm:

```
sudo apt -y update && sudo apt -y upgrade

curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

sudo apt -y update && sudo apt -y upgrade
sudo apt -y autoremove
```

Then, change directories into your app directory:

```
cd myapp/ #Change this to match your app directory
```

Remove node_modules folder

```
sudo rm -rf node_modules/
```

Then reinstall the packages:

```
npm i
```

See if your app builds successfully:

```
npm run build
```

Comment: This worked great for me on an OrangePiZero2 running debian. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Use 14+ of node.js version
just use nvm -version_name

Answer (score 5):

I got this error with an app created with `create-react-app` v5.0.0, when I was using node v16 (via `nvm`). Downgrading the project to node 14.18.12 fixed the issue for me (I also deleted `node_modules` and ran `npm install` again).

Comment: updating from v10... to v14.19.2 helped me

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this while using Eslint.
Upon running, `npm run lint`, the error appeared.
I have various Node versions on my dev machine and I noticed that I had run the command using v10.

When I switched to v16, the command worked.

###### Cause of the error:

Using incompatible Node versions.

###### Solution

Change Node.js versions (I use Node Version Manager - `nvm` to do this).

Answer (score 1):

Now node 19.x is released and the 18.x is the recommended version
if you want to upgrade your node version, simply you can change this line

```bash
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
```

to

```bash
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -
```

and

```bash
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x | sudo -E bash -
```

for latest version

Answer (score -1):

You can try

curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall