# React not found root element

Tags: reactjs

My questions is when I run react app I see exception about webpack cannot load container (div id="root"), but I have ClientApp/public/index.html file with this element. And this project normal starts on my collegue. I don't understand what could be the problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: show us the content of your `index.js` please. This is where React target the container.

Comment: [QuentinGrisel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9868549/quentin-grisel), Thanks, I updated post.

Comment: I think you're trying to solve the wrong error. The `Module.createRequire is not a function` suggests you might have an outdated version of npm/node (Which would line up with it working correctly on your colleagues machine) [Relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70390777/error-in-module-createrequire-is-not-a-function/70392769)

Comment: [DBS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1650337/dbs), thanks, I thought about it, but on the current machine there is no way to update node. I try it on another machine, think this will probably help. Thanks.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved. Problem was in low version node.js