# Getting "Html Webpack Plugin: Error: Child compilation failed: Module.createRequire is not a function" when trying to run React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, plugins, npm-start

Trying to run npm start within my React app is causing the following:

```
  Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module.createRequire is not a function
  
  - child-compiler.js:169 childCompiler.runAsChild
    [fit_with_us]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:169:18
  
  - Compiler.js:551 finalCallback
    [fit_with_us]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:551:5
  
  - Compiler.js:577 compile
    [fit_with_us]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:577:11
  
  - Compiler.js:1196 hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err
    [fit_with_us]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1196:17
```

I've tried deleting my node_modules and package-lock. I've tried deleting my cache. I've tried upgrading my node version to 14 and 16. No luck. Any ideas?

Comment: What are your dependencies? Did you also try to update them or npm?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR in Module.createRequire is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70390777/error-in-module-createrequire-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @cachius Turns out my nvm use command didn't stick. I was using node v10 even after I ran the command. I ran it properly, ran the app, and it worked

Answer (score 3):

[Module.createRequire](https://nodejs.org/api/module.html#modulecreaterequirefilename) was added in node 12.2.0. This error means code written for node >=12.2.0 is run with node < 12.2.0.

This can be caused [unintentionally](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/321) by a [non](/q/47017812) [sticky](/q/24585261) `nvm use` command.

Answer (score 0):

Update the node version on Linux through the steps below, which fixed the issue I also encountered.

Step1:

> sudo apt-get install curl

Step2 (the 18.x is the latest version) :

> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -

Step3:

> sudo apt-get install nodejs

Step4 (check version):

> node -v

Then run npm start that would be fixed.